# Transferring locally built Minecraft world to a remote server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

A little over a year ago, we lost community's Minecraft server due to technical difficulties and not having a proper world backup. I am now considering rebuilding the map in my leisure time. And eventually I would like to upload the map to a new server for my community to play on.

Is this as simple as dropping the world file onto an online server? or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer the world files to your servers root directory (next to the `minecraft_server.jar`).

You will need to change your worldname in `server.properties` to reflect the folder where the world data is stored.

IE, if your world is called test, you will have a directory called `test` with `level.dat` inside it.

In `server.properties` you need to change `world-name=test` in order for it to read it.